# Как заставить сайт воспринимать РНР скрипт как полноценный браузер?

Tags: php

Граблю контент со страницы, но страница его отдаёт только браузерам, скриптам без соответствующих заголовков выводит что-то на подобие:

> "If you can read this something went wrong :( Also, if you're using the Internet Explorer, you should really consider changing to a better browser."

Как обойти?

Comment: Напиши адрес страницы, и код скрипта. А то получается тема есть, а советовать или ругать никто не может.

Answer (score 4):

В curl сессию добавьте:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.51");
```

Comment: Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource in Z:\.......\index.php on line 3

Как избавиться?

Comment: Туплю.
$ch = curl_init();
Добавил.
Но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Выложите весь код для наглядности.